# how to drop rows where the addition of two column values do not equal a third?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have columns:
'RESIDENT UNITS'
'COMMERICAL UNITS'
'TOTAL UNITS'

I would like to remove rows where 'RESTIDENT UNITS' + 'COMMERICAL UNITS' != 'TOTAL UNITS'

Thanks.!

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'RESIDENT UNITS' : [1,2,3],
                   'COMMERICAL UNITS' : [2,3,4],
                   'TOTAL UNITS' : [3,4,7]})
df

df_new = df.loc[df['RESIDENT UNITS'] + df['COMMERICAL UNITS'] == df['TOTAL UNITS']]
df_new
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
#create df with values that do not equal total
df = pd.DataFrame({'Residential':[5, 10, 15, 20],
                    'Commercial':[5, 10, 15, 20],
                    'Total':[10, 20, 30, 50]})

# Create an empty list
Row_list = []

# Iterate over each row
for index, rows in df.iterrows():
    # Create list for the current row
    my_list = [rows.Residential, rows.Commercial, rows.Total]

    # append the list to the final list
    Row_list.append(my_list)

#find which columns do not add to total and remove them
for i, x in enumerate(Row_list):
    if x[0] + x[1] != x[2]:
        Row_list.remove(x)

#transpose back into correct format of rows and columns
Column_list = [list(x) for x in zip(*Row_list)]

#create new df
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'Residential':Column_list[0],
                    'Commercial':Column_list[1],
                    'Total':Column_list[2]})
#print
print(new_df)
```

here is a relatively long way to do it but shows step by step of the process